# How to retrieve value from a data frame "between" two conditions

Tags: r, dataframe

Can I get value between, for example x-1:x+1, from data frame in R?

if I have data.frame

```
A <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)

B <- c(2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
```

and I have `x = 2`, how to get value that **x-1 <= A <= x+1**
so the result is

```
A B
1 2
2 3
3 4
```

Comment: hehe, forget to add df<-data.frame(A,B) sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's see...

```
df <- data.frame(A=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8), B=c(2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9))
x <- 2
df[df$A <= x+1 & df$A >= x-1,]
##   A B
## 1 1 2
## 2 2 3
## 3 3 4
```

Comment: Thankyou, Idont now whats wrong with me, I've tried that code before but it doesnt work =_= and the code that you give to me its work, thankyou once again :D

Comment: doneee :D thankyou for your explanation, i'm new here